# How Do I use Values from another file in shell?

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement, terminal, logic

Right now I am trying to right a script that will check the values from a .properties file against a group of set values in a script

But for some reason when I call the values they wont match up right, this is what I have so far, I believe maybe the .properties values are being stored right

```
#!/bin/bash 
SuccessfulDiffRun="true" 
timestamp() { date +"%a %d %b %Y"; }
TodaysDate=$(timestamp)
echo ""
echo $TodaysDate
echo ""
#Properties Call
file="savedState.properties" 
#Echo out the file
while read LINE; do echo "$LINE"; done < savedState.properties

#Check Values Hotpatch.
echo ""
echo "Running Checks HotPatch..."
if [ "$TodaysDate" = "$WD_MANAGEGOLD_DATETIMESTAMP" ]; then
    echo Dates Are A Match
    if [ "$SuccessfulDiffRun" = "$WD_MANAGEGOLD_SUCCESS" ]; then
        echo Diff Run Successful
        echo Hotpatch Run Was Successful
    else
        echo Diff Run Not Successful
        exit 0
    fi
else
    echo Dates Not A Match
    exit 0 
fi

#Check Values RC.
echo ""
echo "Running Checks RC..."
if [ "$TodaysDate" = "$WD_MANAGERC_DATETIMESTAMP" ]; then
    echo Dates Are A Match
    if [ "$SuccessfulDiffRun" = "$WD_MANAGERC_SUCCESS" ]; then
        echo Diff Run Successful
        echo RC Run Was Successful
    else
        echo Diff Run Not Successful
        exit 0
    fi
else
    echo Dates Not A Match
    exit 0 
fi
```

and the values in the .properties file

```
WD_MANAGEGOLD_DATETIMESTAMP=Wed 21 May 2015 
WD_MANAGEGOLD_SUCCESS=false
WD_MANAGERC_DATETIMESTAMP=Wed 21 May 2015 
WD_MANAGERC_SUCCESS=false
```

any help would be great

Comment: And when you do `source filename` or `. filename` in your present script to read the `WD_MANA...` files into your present script, I would recommend quoting the files in your .properties file (e.g. `WD_MANAGERC_DATETIMESTAMP="Wed 21 May 2015"` )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables won't be created if yo just `read` the .properties file. Each line is stored in `LINE`, and if you want to execute the string as code, use `eval`:

```
while read LINE; do eval $LINE; done < savedState.properties
```

**But** make sure to quote the string which contains spaces inside, as

```
WD_MANAGEGOLD_DATETIMESTAMP="Wed 21 May 2015"
WD_MANAGEGOLD_SUCCESS=false
WD_MANAGERC_DATETIMESTAMP="Wed 21 May 2015"
WD_MANAGERC_SUCCESS=false
```

Another trick is just source the files as a script:

```
source savedState.properties
```

or

```
. savedState.properties
```

which are identical.

Besides, timestamp does not mean a string representing a date like 'Wed 21 May 2015'. Timestamp means the number of seconds(or milliseconds) from 01/01/1970. It's a number, not a string.

Comment: When I try and use the source command, I get savedState.properties: line 1: 21: command not found, savedState.properties: line 3: 21: command not found any idea why ?

Comment: @ClarkPamler93 I tried on my machine and the `source` works, I guess you missed to quote `Wed 21 May 2015`. Because if you evaluate `xx=Wed 21`(instead of `xx="Wed 21"`, notice the quotes),  `Wed` will be assigned to `xx` and `21` will be taken as a command.

Answer (score 0):

Make a function get_value that looks in the properties file.

```
function get_value {
   grep "^${1}=" savedState.properties | cut -d= -f2-
}
...
WD_MANAGERC_DATETIMESTAMP="$(get_value WD_MANAGERC_DATETIMESTAMP)"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have different options to make it working. 
First of all it's "Wed 21 May 2015" won't match with anything because it's "Thu 21 May 2015"... but that's a detail.

If you parse a file which contains bash variable definition you need to replace echo

```
...
while read LINE; do echo "$LINE"; done < savedState.properties
...
```

with eval (and eventually remove the `"`)

```
...
while read LINE; do eval $LINE; done < savedState.properties
...
```

You can laso replace the full line with a simple `source savedState.properties`

Finally  protect the string definition in the properties file with `"`

```
WD_MANAGEGOLD_DATETIMESTAMP="Thu 21 May 2015"
WD_MANAGEGOLD_SUCCESS="false"
WD_MANAGERC_DATETIMESTAMP="Thu 21 May 2015"
WD_MANAGERC_SUCCESS="false"
```

Best, 
V.

Answer (score 0):

If you do `source` the `.properties` file (or whatever its final name) in your current script, the proper way to do it is to first check that it exists and is readable, then `source`:

```
#!/bin/bash
...
[ -r ".properties" ] && . ".properties" || {
    printf "error: source of file '.properties' failed, exiting"
    exit 1
}
```